# NodeJS / Mongoose / Express - Unable to delete item from db on click

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm able to add and read from the database currently, but when I click the delete link I created in the view, I'm given an error "Cannot GET /destroy/".

Here's some my code:

```
var Person = require('.././schema.js');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

exports.create = function(req, res) {
new Person({
empName: req.body.empName,
role: req.body.role,
wage: req.body.wage,
update: Date.now()
}).save(function(err, people){
people.details();
res.redirect('/');
});
};

exports.destroy = function(req, res) {
Person.findById( req.params.id, function ( err, people) {
people.remove( function( err, people) {
  console.log("Destroyed: " + people + " successfully!");
  res.redirect( '/' );
});
});
};
```

View:

```
<h3><%= title %></h3>
<blockquote>
 <ul>
 <% for(var i = 0; i < peopleList.length; i++) { %>
  <li class="litext"><strong>Name:</strong> <%= peopleList[i].empName %><strong>Role:</strong> <%= peopleList[i].role %> <strong>Wage:</strong> <%= peopleList[i].wage %></li>
  <span class="litext"><a href="/destroy/<%= peopleList._id %>" title="Delete Person">Delete</a></span>
<% }; %>
</ul>
</blockquote>
```

From app.js:

```
var port = process.env.port || 4000; 
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var forms = require('./controllers/forms');
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); // for mongoDB
var Person = require('./schema.js'); // db schema
var app = express();

app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.use(bodyParser());
app.get('/destroy/:id', forms.destroy);
app.post('/submit', forms.create);
```

I didn't include any code from the controllers, don't think that is necessary as I think the issue is with routing.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are not passing the ID while calling the destroy method. Replace the below line:

```
<a href="/destroy/<%= peopleList._id %>
```

With

```
<a href="/destroy/<%= peopleList[i]._id %>"
```

Comment: Please mark this as the answer if it fixed your issue.